# distribution function lebesgue measure

Tags: probability

I have a random variable X with law $\mu={2 \over 5} \delta_{2}+{1 \over 5} \delta_{-2}+{1 \over 5}\lambda_{[0,2]}$. ( $\lambda$ is lebesgue measure )

I know $F_{X}(t)=P(X\le t)$ but how can i find it in this case?

Comment: As you wrote:
$F_X(t)=P(X\le t)=\int_{[- \infty;t]} x d\mu$ ... can you evaluate this last integral?

Comment: $F_{X}(t)=0$ if $t < -2$;$F_{X}(t)={1 \over 5}$ if $-2\le t < 0$ but if $0\le t<2$?

Comment: That's a start. Now go on computing all the values for different values of $t$.

Comment: if $0\le{t}<2$ is ${ 1 \over {5} }$+ ${ 1 \over {5}} {\int_{0}^{2}\, dt}$?

Comment: almost... the upper bound for the integral is $t$, hence the total evaluates to $\frac15 + \frac1t\int_0^tdt=\frac15+\frac15t=\frac15(1+t)$. And for $t\ge 2$ you get $\frac15 + \frac25 +\frac15=1$.